# Strange behavior of windbg alias in loops

Tags: windbg

I am trying to master windbg aliases (e.g. the *aS* command) and have run into a behavior I cannot understand.  This is a nasty issue (as least to me) and I would love to understand it, so any help is really appreciated.

In general I think I understand the alias evaluation process (e.g. the need for a new statement block to force a new evaluation).

I've boiled down the issue to the following statements.  First this one:

```
ad *; .foreach /s (var "aaa bbb ccc") { ;aS ${/v:foo} var; .echo foo}
```

This outputs

```
foo
aaa
bbb
```

So it is "one iteration behind" which I understand because the statement *.echo foo* is does not have the alias *foo* re-evaluated.  So I enclose that statement in a statement block, *.block {.echo foo}*

```
ad *; .foreach /s (var "aaa bbb ccc") { ;aS ${/v:foo} var; .block {.echo foo}}
```

Now it echoes

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

as expected and desired.  However I find that if I just insert add *any* character between the statement *.echo foo* and the closing curly brace for the block (e.g. whitespace or a semicolon)

```
ad *; .foreach /s (var "aaa bbb ccc") { ;aS ${/v:foo} var; .block {.echo var foo }}
```

then I get the output

```
aaa
aaa
bbb
```

So my questions are:

1. Why does this happen?  I have a statement block to force alias re-evaluation, how can an innocuous character make a difference?
2. Even if the extra character somehow breaks the expected/desired alias substitution, why doesn't it do so the first time through the loop?  If it is broken the output should be the same as the first example, with the first iteration producing "foo" not "aaa".
3. How can I make this work as desired (an alias re-evaluation each time through the loop)?  I can't always have a closing curly brace after the alias name, I might need to use it in the middle of a statement.  I tried using the syntax *${foo}* but that didn't change anything.

Also I tried using a *.for* loop with a pseudo-register rather than a *.foreach* loop with strings, and the results were exactly the same - as expected/desired if and only if I had a closing brace after the alias name in the statement *.echo foo*.

```
ad *; .for (r $t0=0; @$t0<3; r $t0=@$t0+1) {;aS /c ${/v:foo} r @$t0; .block{.echo foo}}
```

and the results were the same - alias evaluation correct if and only if there is a closing curly brace after *.echo foo*, otherwise it is one-behind (except for the first time through the loop when it is correct).

Also, the issue does not seem to be the alias definition statement itself *aS ${/v:foo} var*.  If I insert an *al* command after *aS ${/v:foo}*, then the aliases are listed as expected.  So the issue is in the statement that *uses* the alias *.echo foo*.  This should work as long as it is enclosed in a statement block.  Please help!

Thanks,
Dave

Quick update: I am starting to think this is an actual bug in windbg although I don't see how since it breaks aliases in loops which seems like a significant bug.  In the MS documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-aliases there is an example that is essentially the same as the ones I give above:

```
ad *
.foreach (value {dd 61000 L4}) 
{
  as /x ${/v:myAlias} value + 1
  .block{.echo value myAlias }
}
```

This works as the documentation says as long as the *.block{}* is present.  But just as in my examples, introducing *any* character after the alias name in the statement *.echo value myAlias* produces output that is one-behind (just as if there was no *.block{}*), except for the first iteration.  So the only reason this example from the documentation works is that it happens to follow the alias name *myAlias* with an immediate curly brace.

Comment: Why does this happen? - Because WinDbg. Do not try to understand everything. It will make you sad and drive you crazy.

Comment: If you want to do scripting, use pyKD, write an extension yourself or use [some other extensions](https://github.com/anhkgg/awesome-windbg-extensions)

Comment: True windbg is brutal and if I am going to do heavy debugger scripting I guess I need to use an extension as you suggest.  But sometimes that doesn't help like if you inherit a bunch of windbg debugger scripts that need to be understood and maintained...

Comment: That's true. And sometimes, extensions won't work in production environments. E.g. PyKD needs a Python installation, which you might not have when doing production debugging. That's also the reason why I often stick with "native" WinDbg scripts. They work everywhere -- well, "work", sort of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the alias at the end:

```
2:007> .foreach /s (var "aaa bbb ccc") { ;aS ${/v:foo} ${var}; .block { .echo ${var} ${foo} and so }; ad ${/v:foo}}
aaa aaa and so
bbb bbb and so
ccc ccc and so
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, this is a step in the right direction.  Ultimately I guess I just shouldn't try anything complex with windbg scripting but use an extension as suggested.  Still I would like to understand things completely if possible.  I simplified my example to get rid of the loops and asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70875274/windbg-alias-replacement-broken-simplified-example.  I am just wondering if windbg aliases are really that broken.  The behavior does not match the documentation at all.

Comment: @DavidStone: WinDbg has too many documentation bugs, unfortunately. Nowadays, Microsoft might have the documentation open sourced on Github, so you could start adding issues there and even provide pull request. I doubt that they will fix anything in their scripting engine. They rather develop new stuff like JavaScript support.

Answer (score 1):

starting with ad*; will err if there is no alias previously  defined are you sure it worked with no alias ? do as Thomas answered delete the alias after using it .

try using some thing like this

```
0:000> .foreach /s (var "sugar honey tea lemongrass  ginger") {;aS ${/v:foo} var; .block{.echo my foo is mixed with milk ;ad *}  }
my sugar is mixed with milk
my honey is mixed with milk
my tea is mixed with milk
my lemongrass is mixed with milk
my ginger is mixed with milk
0:000>
```

Comment: Thanks yes deleting the alias before using it seems to work - I posted a question with a simplified example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70875274/windbg-alias-replacement-broken-simplified-example.  Still this seems like the documentation is simply wrong, it doesn't say anything about needing to delete an alias before aliases are evaluated.  These are just examples, I'd really like to fully understand the behavior whatever it is...