# Windbg alias replacement broken? Simplified example

Tags: windbg

Yesterday I asked a question about the behavior of windbg aliases ([Strange behavior of windbg alias in loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70860127/strange-behavior-of-windbg-alias-in-loops)) and got some helpful answers.

Now I have a simplified example that shows the behavior I am seeing, without any loops.  It seems like alias replacement is simply broken, and the documentation about *.block {}* is basically wrong.

In a *foo.windbg* script I have the following:

```
;aS ${/v:foo} 1
al
.block 
{
  .echo foo
}
```

I run the script with

```
$$><foo.windbg
```

If the alias *foo* is not defined before running the script (or if it is already defined to *1*), this works as expected.  However if I already have *foo* defined to a different value, e.g. *0*

```
;aS ${/v:foo} 0
```

then when I run the script *foo* gets set to 1 (I can see that from the *al* command in the script) but the command *.echo foo* in the script produces *0*.  Even the reference to *foo* is in a *.block{}*.

It works if the closing curly brace in the block statement is immediately after the reference to *foo*

```
;aS ${/v:foo} 1
al
.block 
{
  .echo foo}
```

This doesn't help because it means you can't use the alias unless it happens to be at the end of a *.block{}* or other compound statement.  I though referencing the alias with *${foo}* would help but it does not.

From the answers to my previous question I see that deleting (*ad*) the alias before setting it seems to fix the problem in some cases.  Just using

```
ad foo
```

will error out the script if *foo* is not defined so I can't use it.  Using

```
ad *
```

works but deletes all aliases including ones I have already created and want to use.  I tried

```
.if (${/d:foo}) {ad ${/v:foo}}
```

but that gives the same behavior, where foo is replaced with the old value when used further down in the script.  So I guess the work-around is to start the script with

```
aS ${/v:foo} dummy
ad ${/v:foo}
```

which seems to work.

So the basic problem is that alias replacement fails (in some cases) unless the alias name is followed by the closing curly brace of certain statements like *.block*.  All the examples from the windbg documentation just so happen to do exactly this, and/or delete all aliases first and work around the problem that way.

I know I'm beating the dead horse but does this behavior have an explanation?  Am I confused?  It seems simply broken and, for the way I want to use aliases, useless.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62283889/windbg-passing-pseudo-registers-to-extensions-and-scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have many questions. It's about deleting aliases, using aliases, running scripts, understanding WinDbg ...

### Deleting aliases

One of them is "How to delete an alias without knowing in advance whether it's defined or not?" The answer to that is `.block{ad /q ${/v:foo}}`.

### How to use aliases in your scripts

The next thing I'd advise for is: do not use aliases without the alias syntax. This is not so much for WinDbg itself, but rather for the readers of your script and for maintainability.

When I see a line

```
.echo foo
```

then I expect it to print "foo" and nothing else. When I see a line

```
.echo ${foo}
```

then I know that there is a variable or alias involved.

### Conceptual bug with aliases: unable to escape them

Actually I think this is a conceptual bug, because there's no reliable way in WinDbg to echo a literal "foo", but in most echo scenarios I just want it to do that and nothing else

```
0:000> as foo oops
0:000> .echo foo
oops
0:000> .echo "foo"
oops
0:000> .echo ${foo}
oops
0:000> .echo "${foo}"
oops
0:000> .echo ${/v:foo}
${/v:foo}
0:000> .echo "${/v:foo}"
${/v:foo}
0:000> .printf "foo"
oops
0:000> .printf "${foo}"
oops
0:000> .printf "${/v:foo}"
${/v:foo}
```

And then you find bugs like you do:

```
0:000> .printf "foo\n"
foo
```

### Your use of aliases

I appreciate that you provide small MREs to reproduce your issues. From what I see it looks like you're trying to use aliases like variables.

Let's think about what an alias is: You use aliases on Linux if you have a command that you need often but it's too long or complicated to type. I have aliases defined like `ll` for `ls -l` and `cd..` for `cd ..` because I'm somewhat used to the Windows syntax.

The problem is: a WinDbg alias is not an alias as you know it from Linux. It's more like a preprocessor definition doing a stupid search and replace.

In the cases you presented so far, it has nothing to do with having an abbreviation for shorter typing or circumventing typing mistakes. You seem to assign it a value. In that case you should consider using pseudo registers like `$t1`.

### Running scripts

You are running the script with `$$><` and that method has the property of

> Condenses to single command block: Yes

What it will do: it concatenates all lines in the file by a semicolon. Any you have to live with the consequences of that. See "further reading" on how that causes problems.

### Further reading

It seems you [want to understand WinDbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62283889/windbg-passing-pseudo-registers-to-extensions-and-scripts). That post will make you scratch your head and facepalm. What you'll learn there:

- You can't simply concatenate commands using `;` as a separator
- You can't simply write empty statements
- WinDbg is whitespace sensitive (sometimes)
- A line is not always a line
- String escaping is broken
- Comments are not always comments

### But why?

Warning: pure speculation ahead. I have never worked for Microsoft.

Why is that? WinDbg exists for an incredibly long time. The oldest version I have on my computer is version 4.0.18 from 1999, likely developed for Windows NT 4 SP 6. I can imagine that WinDbg 3 versions for Windows NT 3 existed as well, so it potentiall goes back to 1993.

At that time, there were no IDE features like "Find references" or "Find usages", so it was quite hard to do an impact analysis and I believe it was often unclear to developers what side effects a new command like `as` could have.

Combined with the impression of WinDbg being a Microsoft internal tool only and "the developers will know what they are doing" gives us a useful but overall buggy tool today.

WinDbg was probably not developed with a clear roadmap in mind. It probably does not have something you'd call "architecture". Some developer was debugging something complicated and thought it would be great to provide a sort of script to others in order to make debugging easier. So WinDbg is likely more a collection of useful code snippets we call commands today, but they have no common lexer or parser, for example.

Comment: 0:000> .printf "\"foo\"\n"
"foo"

Comment: @blabb: yes, close. Is it possible without printing the quotes?

Comment: you cant print many charecters without escaping in most basic languages .windbg .printf is loosely coupled with c syntax  so you need to escape btw you seem to have no problems escaping linefeed  \n so why differential treatment to quotes  :)

Comment: Wow thanks for taking the time to educate me a bit on some windbg details, in this answer and your answer to the other question that you linked to.  Some of things you cover I already knew, some I understood only vaguely, and others were completely new to me...I even learned some new commands like ~e.

Comment: I guess I just have to accept these quirks as bugs.  Because even with the better understanding I have it makes no sense that alias replacement works if *either* the alias name is followed by a }, and/or the alias is deleted (in a certain way) before being set.  It has to be deleted with "aS ${/v:foo} dummy; ad ${/v:foo}"...using ".block{ad /q ${/v:foo}}" as you suggest deletes the alias but the alias replacement later in the script still uses the old value of foo if foo is not followed by }.

Comment: It's a bit irritating that the examples in the documentation like ".foreach (value {dd 610000 L4})  {as /x ${/v:myAlias} value + 1; .block{.echo value myAlias}}; ad myAlias" work only because the alias name "myAlias" is followed by a }.  That example is supposed to be instructing the reader on how to use aliases but it just happens to get lucky, changing it slightly to ".echo myAlias hello" breaks it.

Comment: BTW the reason I wanted to use aliases and not pseudo-registers is that 1. Aliases can take any value not just numbers.  2. They can have descriptive names like IsWorkerThreadBlocked.  3. You can have any number of aliases, it seems pseudo-registers are limited to $t0 to $t19.

Comment: @DavidStone: I can't agree more. WinDbg has quirks, glitches, bugs, you name it. I have contacted the WinDbg team regarding fixes in the documentation, but I never received feedback. I don't even know if someone received my emails. Nothing changed in WinDbg documentation from my feedback, so I gave up.

Answer (score 0):

i don't see a solid use case in the query so i wont go into the alias debate ;

also the query is a  bit of an xy problem because you think using alias is the way out for your contrived problem instead of talking about what the actual problem you are trying to solve .

but if you want some modern UserVariables try checking out Javascript you can probably pull what you want out to a standard es6 compliant framework

```
0:000> dx Debugger.State.UserVariables
Debugger.State.UserVariables                
0:000> dx @$foo = "sugar"
@$foo = "sugar"  : sugar
    Length           : 0x5
    
0:000> dx @$blah = "honey"
@$blah = "honey" : honey
    Length           : 0x5

0:000> dx -r0 "i want "+ @$foo+ " mixed With "+@$blah
"i want "+ @$foo+" mixed With "+@$blah : i want sugar mixed With honey
```

just to complete the loop here is a javascript that compares a user provided argument with an already existing UserVariable and does some debugprinting

```
"use strict";
function foo(argu) 
{
    for (var i in host.namespace.Debugger.State.UserVariables)
    {
            if(i===argu)
            {
                host.diagnostics.debugLog("hi " + i +" with me ");
                var tmp = "host.namespace.Debugger.State.UserVariables." + i
                var boo = eval(tmp)
                host.diagnostics.debugLog(boo +"\n")                
            }
    }    
}
```

create few user variables with

```
dx @$foo = "sugar"
dx @$bar = "honey"
dx @$blah = "milk"
0:000> dx Debugger.State.UserVariables
Debugger.State.UserVariables                
    foo              : sugar
    bar              : honey
    blah             : milk
```

load the script and play with it

```
0:000> .scriptload d:\test.js
JavaScript script successfully loaded from 'd:\test.js'
0:000> dx @$scriptContents.foo("bar")
hi bar with me honey
@$scriptContents.foo("bar")
0:000> dx @$scriptContents.foo("foo")
hi foo with me sugar
@$scriptContents.foo("foo")
0:000> dx @$scriptContents.foo("blah")
hi blah with me milk
@$scriptContents.foo("blah")
```